# modify captured array c++11 lambda function

Tags: c++11, capture, lambda, c++-cx

I'm writing an Windows phone application with C++/CX. The function tries to copy input array to output array asynchronously:

```
IAsyncAction CopyAsync(const Platform::Array<byte, 1>^ input, Platform::WriteOnlyArray<byte, 1>^ output) 
{
    byte *inputData = input->Data;
    byte *outputData = output->Data;
    int byteCount = input->Length;
    // if I put it here, there is no error
    //memcpy_s(outputData, byteCount, inputData, byteCount);
    return concurrency::create_async([&]() -> void {
        memcpy_s(outputData, byteCount, inputData, byteCount); // access violation exception
        return;
    });
}
```

This function compiles but cannot run correctly and produces an "Access violation exception". How can I modify values in the output array?

Comment: The value of `output->Data` changed between the time you captured it at the top of the function and used it inside the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Undefined Behaviour: by the time you use your 3 captured (by reference) variables `inputData/outputData/byteCount` in the lambda, you already returned from `CopyAsync` and the stack has been trashed.

It's really the same issue as if you returned a reference to a local variable from a function (which we know is evil), except that here the references are hidden inside the lambda so it's a bit harder to see at first glance.

---

If you are **sure** that `input` and `output` won't change and will still be reachable between the moment you call `CopyAsync` and the moment you run the asynchronous action, you can capture your variables by value instead of by reference:

```
return concurrency::create_async([=]() -> void {
//                                ^ here
    memcpy_s(outputData, byteCount, inputData, byteCount);
    return;
});
```

Since they're only pointers (and an `int`), you won't be copying the pointed-to data, only the pointers themselves.

---

Or you could just capture `input` and `output` by value: since they're garbage-collected pointers this will at least make sure the objects are still reachable by the time you run the lambda:

```
return concurrency::create_async([=]() -> void {
    memcpy_s(output->Data, input->Length, input->Data, input->Length);
    return;
});
```

I for one prefer this second solution, it provides more guarantees (namely, object reachability) than the first one.

Comment: I think your reason was correct but both of your suggestions did not solve my problem, I still got an Access violation exception. I think the problem was that the function only captured the pointer to data, not the data it self even if they were captured by values. How can I capture the whole array into lambda function?

Comment: I believe the second one *should* work if you don't manually delete or otherwise modify your `input/output` objects after calling `CopyAsync` (although I'm not quite familiar with MS' `^` weird GC pointer). Are you somehow trying to reuse those objects after `CopyAsync`? As to capturing the array by value, it would probably work but then you'd make one copy synchronously (capture) and then another one asynchronously (lambda), which doesn't make much sense: you might as well do the copy synchronously once and for all.